# How to get word embeddings from the pretrained transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, transfer-learning, transformer-model

I am working on a word-level classification task on multilingual data, I am using XLM-R, I know that XLM-R uses `sentencepiece`  as tokenizers which sometimes tokenizes words into subword.

> For example the sentence "deception master" is tokenized as `de` `ception` `master`, the word deception has been tokenized into two sub-words.

How can I get the embedding of `deception`. I can take the mean of the subwords to get the embedding of the word as done [here](https://github.com/uhh-lt/bert-sense/blob/bfecb3c0e677d36ccfab4e2131ef9183995efaef/BERT_Model.py#L342).  But I have to implement my code in TensorFlow and TensorFlow computational graph doesn't support NumPy.

I could store the final hidden embeddings after taking the mean of the subwords into a NumPy array and give this array as input to the model, but I want to fine-tune the transformer.

How to get the word embeddings from the sub-word embeddings given by the transformer

Comment: Are you referring to the positional encoding?

Comment: no, I require the encoding of each word in a sentence from the transformer

Comment: This seems to be what huggingface-transformers use: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py#L117

Comment: I have no understanding of how the internals works for this, but can't you use the ```BertTokenizer``` in the link above to get the word embedding? The ```_tokenize``` method looks like what you are looking for, but there might be a public endpoint for using this tokenizer in the huggingface-transformers library.

Comment: No, the _tokenize method gives me tokenized representation version of my input. I want  the embedding of the words which has been split into two subwords

Comment: Your questions is not clear. Do you want to know how to get token embeddings from the model or do you want to know how to take multiple sub-word embeddings and turn into one?

Comment: I wanted to know how to take multiple sub-words embeddings and turn them into one, my input would be (batch size, seq length, 768). I want to take mean along the axis 1

Comment: If getting the mean of the embedings of the subwords is suitable for you, why don't you use `tf.math.reduce_mean`? Computational graphs support all TF functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining subword embeddings into words for word labeling is not how this problem is usually approached. The usual approach is the opposite: keep the subwords as they are, but adjust the labels to respect the tokenization of the pre-trained model.

One of the reasons is that the data is typically in batches. When merging subwords into words, every sentence in the batch would end up having a different length which would require processing each sentence independently and pad the batch again – this would be slow. Also, if you do not average the neighboring embeddings, you get more fine-grained information from the loss function, which tells explicitly what subword is responsible for an error.

When tokenizing using SentencePiece, you can get the indices in the original string:

```py
from transformers import XLMRobertaTokenizerFast
tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base")
tokenizer("deception master", return_offsets_mapping=True)
```

This returns the following dictionary:

```
{'input_ids': [0, 8, 63928, 31347, 2],
 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'offset_mapping': [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 9), (10, 16), (0, 0)]}
```

With the offsets, you can find out if the subword corresponds to a word that you want to label. There are various strategies that could be used for encoding the labels. The easiest one is just to copy the label to every subword. A more fancy way would be using schemes used in named entity recognition, such as [IOB tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) that explicitly says what is the begging of the labeled segment.